# Regular languages accepted by an automaton with at most one transition per letter

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, regular-language

I'm interested in the (very restricted) subset of regular languages for which there is an automaton having the following property: for every letter $a$ of the alphabet, the automaton has at most one transition labeled with $a$. (Of course, the automaton is then necessarily a partial deterministic automaton.) **Is there a name for this class of regular languages?**

These languages are quite limited but not entirely trivial either, for instance you could have $(ab)^*$, $ab^*|cd^*$, or $(ab)^*a$ (which I guess cannot be written as a regular expression with only one occurrence of each letter, so my class is more general than imposing the analogous requirement on regular expressions). These automata are clearly [local automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Local_automata), so this is a subclass of the local languages. These automata are also [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_finite_state_automaton), so these languages are star-free. Of course, for any alphabet, there are only finitely many languages of this kind over the alphabet.

I thought this class was pretty natural, but looking around, I could not find anything about it. Does it have a name, or has it been studied somehow?

Comment: It seems that your class can be defined as the smallest class $C$ such that every regular language is the projection via a length-preserving morphism of a language from $C$. Maybe this algebraic point of view can help...

Comment: Actually, a deterministic automaton has exactly as many $a$-transitions as it has states. Do you mean something like a “partial deterministic” automaton?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek From the examples I think it means that every other transition goes to a rejection state.

Comment: Yes, I meant partial deterministic. Sorry, I'm used to automata being partial by default, and yes it means that arrows that are not defined implicitly lead to a rejection state. Edited the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @Denis: I agree with your comment, though I'm not sure how to use it. :)

Comment: Also a side remark: if there is an automaton satisfying your constraint, it is necessarily the minimal automaton. So it's easy to decide membership in the class by just computing the minimal automaton.

Comment: They are a subclass of the *reversible* automata but I don't know if they are "studied" or have an "official" name; see for example [On Reversible Automata](https://www.irif.fr/~jep/PDF/Reversible.pdf). Given a DFA you can expand its alphabet to assign an unique letter to each transition, the resulting language is the language of all possible traversals ("traces") of the original DFA.

Comment: @Denis: I'm not too sure I understand why the minimal automaton would work (it's usually taken to be minimal in terms of number of states, not transitions), though clearly it's decidable to test membership as there's a bound on the automaton size and equivalence of regular languages is decidable.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: I didn't know this notion of reversible automata and reversible languages, but I agree my languages are indeed a subclass of reversible languages, thanks!

Comment: @a3nm if an automaton works, then there is no way to further minimize it by merging states, since the outgoing transitions of two different states have completely different labels.

Comment: @Denis: ah, thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Also note that once you fix the alphabet the number of distinct languages you can get with your model is finite ($|Q| \leq |\Sigma|$ must hold); if you consider the languages obtained by incresing $\Sigma$ size, then you get the class of distinct DFA "traces" (as said above).

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: Yes, that was already in my initial question. This is simply because the number of transitions, hence of relevant states, is bounded by the alphabet size.